# FedAuth cookie in Farm using https missing

Tags: forms-authentication

I have an issue where custom providers, I can see that in the development environment the FedAuth cookie is set. But in productions is not. Production has two front end servers, and are accessed using https. Are there any settings that can be checked to see why it is not set?